# Is it possible to detect the following assignment at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

So I have the following case, apologies for the long example, but it should compile correctly:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>


namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

namespace aux
{
template <typename ...Args>
struct to_vector
{ };

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct to_vector<T, Args...>
{ typedef typename mpl::push_front<typename to_vector<Args...>::type, T>::type type; };

template <typename T>
struct to_vector<T>
{ typedef typename mpl::vector<T> type; };

template <>
struct to_vector<>
{ typedef typename mpl::vector<> type; };

template <typename Dest, typename T>
struct tuple_adder
{
  typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Dest>(), std::make_tuple(std::declval<T>()))) type;
};

}

struct foo
{
  struct storage
  { };

  template <typename T>
  struct placeholder : storage
  {
    placeholder(T&& t) : content(t)
    { }

    T content;
  };

  storage* data;


  template <typename ...Args>
  foo(Args&&... args)
  : data()
  {
    typedef typename mpl::fold<
      typename aux::to_vector<Args...>::type,
      std::tuple<>,
      aux::tuple_adder<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>
    >::type tuple_type;
    // Instantiate the tuple
    data = new placeholder<tuple_type>(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }

  template <typename ...Args>
  void set(Args&&... args)
  {
    typedef typename mpl::fold<
      typename aux::to_vector<Args...>::type,
      std::tuple<>,
      aux::tuple_adder<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>
    >::type tuple_type;

    auto tp = static_cast<placeholder<tuple_type>*>(data);
    *tp = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};


int main()
{
  foo f(1, 2., std::string("Hello"));

  f.set(4, 3., std::string("Bar"));

  f.set(3., std::string("Bar"), 3.);
}
```

The idea is simple, `foo` utilises type erasure to store a `tuple` that is constructed via the constructor. Then the restriction should be that `set` is only allowable where the `tuple` generated from the variadic argument list matches the held tuple (which has unfortunately had it's type erased.)

Now I can detect this at runtime using `typeid()`, however, I'd like to know if there is a way I can have the same detection at compile time. The only constraints are that `foo` cannot be templated, and `variant` is out as I want to allow `foo` to be constructed with the fields as necessary (all specified at compile time...)

I fear the answer is that this is not possible (due to the type erasure), however I'm hoping for some ideas of a way to achieve this functionality...

Comment: You want to know if you can detect at compile-time that the runtime value stored in matc... No, sir.

Comment: You can only check it at run-time, but you don't need `typeid` for that, just replace the `static_cast` with `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I'm not interested in the run-time values, I just want to check the types. The above example is slightly convoluted (the step through `mpl::vector` to generate the tuple is there because I have a filter function to remove types I don't want.) As a result, the `set()` must only accept the filtered *types*...

Comment: Erasing the type means making the type is a runtime property.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, sure, but that is a run time check, ideally, given I know the constructed type and the set type *at compile time*, I was hoping that there would be a way to enforce this check at compile time so that a user doesn't need to run it to find out they've passed the fields in the wrong order...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, yip; I was hoping that there may be another smarter way to achieve the same affect... ah well..

Comment: @Nim, yes, I understand the question, that's why I said, "You can only check it at run-time". You _don't_ know the type at compile-time, because you erase the type. If you need to know the type, don't do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I was hoping there would be some dusty corner somewhere in the standard that could be exploited to somehow allow me to accomplish something like the above; but clearly it's not possible, so run-time check it is.... thanks for your input...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of a compile time type system is that it constrains the allowable operations on values of types.  If two objects are the same type then they admit the same allowable operations.

So no, there's no way for the compiler to know what you want to allow, given that you've erased the distinction.

Comment: I could not find a way around the run-time check as long as type erasure is used, so I wanted to delete this question, but you've answered (the correct answer anyway), so I will accept this and leave as is for prosperity...